# How to deal with windows scale in website

Tags: html, css, scale, viewport, aspect-ratio

In windows you can have a screen with different scaling. 100%, 125%, 150% and 175% or even more on 4k resolution. On my 1080p the more scale I have the more zoomed in the website is. How do I make the website looks like the same on every scale as 100% 1.0 as if there is not be zoomed.

I did some research and you can get the scale by javascript with the following
`window.devicePixelRatio`.

I tried the following

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+(1/window.devicePixelRatio)+', maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0')
```

But no help.

Is there anyway?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your function. If I have the meta tag logged in the console *after* your function has been executed, with `console.log(document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"))`, I just get `meta` as result. If I *only* use the console.log line, I get the full meta.

Comment: If I *only* use the console.log line with a viewport meta already in the head, I get the full meta.